# Bitwise OR in bash arguments with square brackets

Tags: linux, bash

I'm familiar with using bitwise OR in general programming, like C, as a way to pass flags to a function call.  But what does this mean in bash? I'm specifically confused about its use in the grep function:

From the linux manual:

```
SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
       grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

What exactly does `[-e PATTERN | -f FILE]` mean?

Also, what does it mean when something is in square brackets?

EDIT: IS there some kind of standard which explains how the linux manual is formatted? I can't find anything about this.

Comment: This just means that those two options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Answer to "EDIT": No. Common sections are semi-standard, but one is free to write the synopsis in any human readable way.

Comment: So, this means in the above command I can only pass one of those flags to bash, never both?

Comment: I just tried and one can specify __both__ `-f file` and  `-e pattern` and the two are OR'd together.  This seems to me to be a man page fail.

Comment: It's not bitwise OR, it's English "either-or".

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193815/how-do-i-use-man-pages-to-learn-how-to-use-commands

Comment: @John1024 Hmm interesting, I never knew `-e` and `-f` can be specified multiple times on the command line, but apparently yes, that's supported, at least in GNU grep or BSD grep.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about reading Unix man pages, not programming. It's answered on unix.stackexchange.com